# Get controller name and subfolder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my controllers organized in subfolders, like this:

```
folder1/controller1
folder1/controller2
folder2/controller1
folder2/controller2
```

I need to get both the controller and the subfolder name, but right now I can only get the controller name using

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->router->class;
```

I also tried this one:

```
$CI->uri->uri_string()
```

But if I call my controller with a method, it will return it too, like this

full url:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/folder1/controller1/index
```

will return

```
folder1/controller1/index
```

instead of

```
folder1/controller1
```

I can do this by using the class name to remove the methods and arguments, but I want to know if there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print_r($this->router);
```

Here you have all the other goodies!

In you case you want `$this->router->directory`

It returns `folders/to/controller/` with a trailing `/`.

**Example:**
Adress: www.example.com/folder1/controller1

`echo $this->router;`

**Outputs:**
`folder1/`

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted!

    $this->router->directory  . $this->router->class